# Typescript: How to declare a Type which represents a Treeview? Is it possible?

Tags: typescript

Typescript is a TYPED superset of JavaScript that compiles into JavaScript, fine!
it helps us to reduce some typos etc etc ok!
I want to create an interface that would be used as an argument in a method. This interface has to represent a treeview that would be used to parse an object.

example: `w1[a2].x[b02].y.z` is the path to access value of `z` in `myObject`

```js
const path = "w1[a2].x[b02].y.z";
const treeOfIdentifiers = {
  "w1": {
    key: "idLvlW",
    "x": {
      key: "idLvlX"
    }
  }
}

const myObject = {
    w0: "Hello Root",
    w1: [{
        idLvlW: "a1",
        x: [{
            idLvlX: "b01",
            y: {
              z: "hello world from w1[a1].x[b01].y.z"
            }
          },
          {
            idLvlX: "b02",
            y: {
              z: "hello world from w1[a1].x[b02].y.z"
            }
          },
          {
            idLvlX: "b03",
            y: {
              z: "hello world from w1[a1].x[b03].y.z"
            }
          },
          {
            idLvlX: "b04",
            y: {
              z: "hello world from w1[a1].x[b04].y.z"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        idLvlW: "a2",
        x: [{
            idLvlX: "b01",
            y: {
              z: "hello world from w1[a2].x[b01].y.z"
            }
          },
          {
            idLvlX: "b02",
            y: {
              z: "hello world from w1[a2].x[b02].y.z"
            }
          },
          {
            idLvlX: "b03",
            y: {
              z: "hello world from w1[a2].x[b03].y.z"
            }
          },
          {
            idLvlX: "b04",
            y: {
              z: "hello world from w1[a2].x[b04].y.z"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        idLvlW: "a3",
        x: [{
            idLvlX: "b01",
            y: {
              z: "hello world from w1[a3].x[b01].y.z"
            }
          },
          {
            idLvlX: "b02",
            y: {
              z: "hello world from w1[a3].x[b02].y.z"
            }
          },
          {
            idLvlX: "b03",
            y: {
              z: "hello world from w1[a3].x[b03].y.z"
            }
          },
          {
            idLvlX: "b04",
            y: {
              z: "hello world from w1[a3].x[b04].y.z"
            }
          }
        ]
      }

    ]
```

**What would be the type|interface of `treeOfIdentifiers` (if not `any`!) if I code using TypeScript?** The thing is to ensure that each node of treeOfIdentifiers, the **property `key` would be provided** and we don't know the structure for the `treeOfIdentifiers` as we don't know the structure of the object to parse!

Comment: So you have a node with key and some value. This value can either be another node or some string? Right?

Comment: I meant This value can either be an array of nodes or some string?

Comment: @FortyTwo key is the exact property we can get, while the others are nodes as many as there are array properties in the object to parse.

Comment: If I have understood you correctly then something like this should work `INode { id: string; data: INode[] | IData[]; }` with `IData { data: string; }`

Comment: Does each node of `treeOfIdentifiers` always have exactly two properties, one being `key` with a `string` value, and the other being some other string key whose value is another node?  Or am I missing something about this?

Comment: hmmm not really! the treeOfIdentifiers (see the question) is a kind of Dictionary of Dictionary (and each node of the Dictionary contains at least one key-value whose  key is "key" and its value is a string, while the other key-values have key whose value is an object that has at least 1 property: "key" whose value is a string (and the other properties are key-value etc.)

Comment: @jcalz : no, it depends on the considered object to parse, if on the same level, the object has 2 properties typed as arrays, there will be... there are as many properties there are arrays properties... do you want me to show a more complex treeOfIdentifiers and the object to parse? ---I'll refine a bit the last sentence in the question....

Comment: as you can see 'treeOfIdentifiers' has 1 property "w1"-meaning the object to parse has a property "w1" that represents an array of objects whose identifier is "idLvlW" <=> key: "idLvlW". Each item in "w1" represents an object that contains a property named "x" that represents an array of objects whose identifier is "idLvlX" <=> key: "idLvlX". As "x" is part of "w1", the treeOfIdentifiers has a node "x" inside the node "w1"... I don't know if it helps

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly difficult thing to express in TypeScript.  For example, adding a string-valued property named `key` to a dictionary of non-`string` values is not straightforward to strongly type... and possibly implies that you might want to make the type simpler (e.g., each node has a `key` property and a `dictionary` property).

I'm not even thinking of making sure that `treeOfIdentifiers` is valid when using it to traverse `myObject`, since you didn't ask about that and this is already very complicated.

But let's see how far we can get, using [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) types:

```
type NonRootOfTreeOfIdentifiers<T> = { [K in 'key' | keyof T]:
  K extends 'key' ? string :
  K extends keyof T ? NonRootOfTreeOfIdentifiers<T[K]> : never
};
type TreeOfIdentifiers<T> = { [K in keyof T]: NonRootOfTreeOfIdentifiers<T[K]> };
const asTreeOfIdentifiers = <T extends TreeOfIdentifiers<T>>(t: T): T => t;
```

The trickiest part of that is in `NonRootOfTreeOfIdentifiers<T>`.  It takes a type `T` representing a non-root node in a valid `treeOfIdentifiers`.  It adds a `key` property to `T`, and then maps these properties of `T` into a new type: `key` is mapped as a `string` property, and every other property is mapped to a `NonRootOfTreeOfIdentifiers<>` version of itself.  So `NonRootOfTreeOfIdentifiers<T>` walks down through the levels of `T` and converts it to another type.  If `T` is a valid non-root node, then `NonRootOfTreeOfIdentifiers<T>` will be a valid non-root node.

The `TreeOfIdentifiers` type function represents the root node, which doesn't require a `key` property, but otherwise traverses down into `NonRootOfTreeOfIdentifiers`.

Finally, the `asTreeOfIdentifiers` function takes an argument of type `T` which is required to be compatible with `TreeOfIdentifiers<T>`, and returns the argument.  Meaning, it will only accept objects conforming to the rules.  So it validates its argument but doesn't change it.

Let's see if it works:

```
const treeOfIdentifiers = asTreeOfIdentifiers({
  "w1": {
    key: "idLvlW",
    "x": {
      key: "idLvlX"
    }
  }
});
```

That compiles, and `treeOfIdentifiers` is inferred to be of type

```
{
    "w1": {
        key: string;
        "x": {
            key: string;
        };
    };
}
```

If you mess up in some way, you will get errors:

```
const missingKey = asTreeOfIdentifiers({
  "w1": {
    key: "idLvlW",
    "x": {
      kee: "idLvlX" // oops
    }
  }
}); 
// error: Property 'key' is missing in type '{ kee: string; }'
```

or

```
const extraProperty = asTreeOfIdentifiers({
  "w1": {
    key: "idLvlW",    
    x: {
      key: "idLvlX"
    }
    y: 123 // oops
  }
}); 
// error: Types of property 'y' are incompatible.
//  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'NonRootOfTreeOfIdentifiers<number>'.
```

So that all works as far as it goes.  I'm not sure it's worth it to you, though.  It gets even hairier if you try to capture the literal string value types like `"idLvlX"` (instead of just `string`).  And, as I said, I haven't even thought about how you'd validate `myObject` against `treeOfIdentifiers` in the type system.

Anyway, good luck.  Hope that helped.

Comment: not bad at all, thanks! This won't work as well : const extraProperty = asTreeOfIdentifiers({
    key:"id",
    "w1": {
        key: "idLvlW",
        x: {
            key: "idLvlX"
        }
    }
});